# How to clear a plot in a `while` loop when using PyQtGraph?

Tags: python, plot, memory-leaks, pyqtgraph

I am using PyQtGraph for a speedy visualization of my data acquisition. For this I am redrawing the data constantly using a `while` loop. A simplified version of this code is given by:

```
import time
import numpy
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore

x = numpy.linspace(-2 * numpy.pi, 2 * numpy.pi, 1000)
y = numpy.cos(x)

# Plot
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.resize(800, 800)

p = win.addPlot()
p.plot(x, y, pen = "y")

i = 0
while i < 5000:
  start_time = time.time()

  noise = numpy.random.normal(0, 1, len(y))
  y_new = y + noise

  p.plot(x, y_new, pen = "y", clear = True)
  p.enableAutoRange("xy", False)

  pg.QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

  i += 1

  end_time = time.time()
  print("It has been {0} seconds since the loop started".format(end_time - start_time))

win.close()
```

When I time each iteration I find that I am not properly clearing the graph. The iteration time just keeps on increasing, and I am slowing down my data acquisition. For the example above, the iteration time in the beginning is about `0.009 s` whereas at the end it is about `0.04 s`. I therefore have a memory-leak.

I know that in `matplotlib` I should be calling be `clf()` to properly clear the plot. Unfortunately I am not that familiar with PyQtGraph and thought the `clear = True` would take care of this issue. I am confident it should be possible as `PyQtGraph` was designed for this type of usage.

How should I clear the graph each iteration to make sure I am not slowing down my data acquisition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call plot on you plotItem, you create a new plotDataItem. All these plotDataItems doesn't seem to clear up properly. You can instead try to use only one plotDataItem and update the contents of it. Do this by using

```
plot = p.plot(x, y, pen = "y")
```

and then inside your loop

```
plot.setData(x, y_new)
```